# Adjusting font size - fixed width or fluid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I'm designing a portfolio page which will contain mostly header text with a few paragraphs and images thrown in for good measure!

My headings and one lined text will expand to fill the entire width of it's container which will be the wrapper.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <h1>I'm a heading</h1>
    <p>I aim to fill just one line regardless of letter count</p>
</div>
```

Now, I have been searching the net for a solution which will allow me to achieve the above. I have found both bigText.js which doesn't work no matter what I do and fitText.js which doesn't automatically size text to it's parent container without editing the .js to find a font size that suits - even then it's not pixel perfect.

My question therefore is, With a wrapper that I wish to keep just 35% of the screen (centred), am I best to keep as a percentage (fluid) or use a fixed width? and with either option, what's the correct way to adjust the font-size to fill the wrapper width correctly?

Thanks in advance,

Simon

Comment: Are you after something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/LUcK2/4/)? Disclaimer: I can only test on Firefox now.

Comment: try percentage for the wdith and em to font sizes

Answer (score 0):

Use percentages and a 'margin:auto' if you want it centered. 
Read up on other frameworks how they work around this problem: 
[Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) works well for my work.